# embedded im-memory database in maven

Tags: java, maven, embedded-database

I've got embedded tomcat setup in `pre-integration` test phase. 
I need to create the same for in-memory database but before the embedded tomcat.

Are any easy&useful maven configuration examples for doing that (for example HSQLDB) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use google you would have found something like this:

https://github.com/avianey/hsqldb-maven-plugin

which exactly is a maven plugin which seemed to be right choice for what you like to do.
The plugin is also available from Maven Central.